# Are there span tables published for repairing a cut roof joist?

Tags: repair, framing, structural, earthquake

A roofing company mistakenly cut a 2 foot section out of a roof joist, on my home.  I'm seeking a reference to what would constitute a proper repair, preferably a prescriptive code or a load table.   I am aware of the American Wood Council tables, but that's for uncut modern lumber and at this point I have neither.

This rafter spanned 14 feet with a mid span support. The roof is flat, with 2x4 rafters at 24 inch on center, topped with 1x6 boards, all nailed.  This is all true dimension rough cut Douglas Fir: good solid stuff.

One end of the cut rafter buts against a brick chimney. The house was built in 1938 and is in an earthquake zone (Hayward Fault).

The roofer said nothing but screwed some plywood on top to cover the gap.

**Update 1:**
The roofer added a patch.  The gap is almost at the center beam.  The patch overlap is 9 inches on the right side, and about 4 inches on the left.  On the left both new and patched rafters straddle the center beam.

The only access is through a 14 inch hole below.

[image: roofer mistake]

**Update 2:**

After consulting with a structural engineer (who wanted 12+ inches of overlap), we ended up compromising a bit.  A filler piece will take compressive load when the chimney slams into the house in a quake:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that your repair is sufficient; I don't think you have enough strength under compression nor do I think that your fastening is enough. I agree with the structural engineer; you want at least 12" of overlap. If you can't get that, then I want to see the old 2x4 attached to the new one by a couple of 3/8 bolts at both ends.

Comment: It's 9 inches of overlap.  With everyone guessing, not presenting test results, it was hard to argue for more from the roofers.  Sure looks janky.  And the roofer ignored the instructions to predrill holes in the 75 year old lumber: several of the stitch plate screws split the wood. @EricGunnerson

Comment: There aren't span tables or anything for public consumption for these types of things, that I know of. This is for an engineer. I have had engineer spec wood splices and I have never seen less than 12" overlap, even where the main load is compression. This looks like a terrible hack job... Are they at least structural screws?

Comment: They are not structural screws. @decker  Hack job is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking here, on the Journal of Light Construction, and consulting with a structural engineer, I was unable to find an answer to the question.  Everyone just guesses when it comes to wood repair, there are no published tables for joints or splices.  If you have a better answer please post it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention where the cut out is but this should take care of it in any respect, as long as the mid span support is a series of posts and not a purlin...
Can you get a 2X6 in there that will give close to a full span? if the material is clean or can be scraped clean, a healthy bead of construction adhesive zig-zagged on the face of the old 2X and screw the 2X6 starting 4 inches from the ends with a pair of screws and 12+/- inches apart in the remainder in pairs also. Use 3 inch drywall screws or 2 3/4 inch SDS screws through the 2X6 into the 2X4. Make sure the screws draw tight the material, pilot if needed with a 3/16" bit.

If you have a mid span support that goes to good bearing through to the foundation, you can use a shorter repair joist, but a single joist that goes over multiple spans is stronger than a single span joist.

FWIW, it looks like a 2X4 will suffice from what I seen the table at page 396 of the 2012 building code (table R802.5.1).

Comment: The room is 14' x 16'.  A 3x6 center beam cantilevers out 8 feet from an adjacent room, to support this half o the roof.  The ceiling is separately supported from both ends.  I have a 14 inch hole, from below, from which to work (a long joist won't fit).  ---- Are there published tables for this type of repair work?

Comment: Save the pic and open it up, you should be able to zoom in so it is readable

Comment: The image is only 317 pixels wide, and unreadabe.  For future searches could you also quote the page & section of the IRC?

Comment: Bummer it started as a 1.7 meg file

Comment: It is on page 396 of the 2012 building code, table R802.5.1

Comment: I had to take some liberties as to which table it was, there other tables that have different criteria live load, dead load, things that are area/climate specific. I also assumed the ceiling joists were not connected the rafters.

Comment: Table R802.5.1 gives me spans for modern lumber in modern construction, but I can't possibly get a full rafter in there. Normally Simson is good for selling braces with tables, but I found nothing on point for patching a 2x4.

Comment: Your repair will be done with modern lumber, and if the mid support is good to truly break the span in half, then the repair can be considered a replacement, even though technically it is being sistered as a repair.

Comment: Consider it like a new roof, the spans can be made the same as your vintage roof with new materials and do the same job, just so happens you only have one new part, instead of a new whole roof.

Comment: The patch will be made with vintage lumber.   I can't get a long piece in, so there will be a splice.  What I'm seeking is a wood splice table (like that available for rebar).

Comment: I don't think drywall screws are a good idea for this repair.  I think in shear the are really weak.  I would stick to SDS screws or nails.

Comment: The vintage lumber still used the same designation, 2X4, 2X6 and so on, just that the actual size was larger than todays material. Wood specie is still the same, fir, pine etc., so the table should work too. Unless you want to try to go as small as possible? You should be able to use a shorter replacement joist as long as the mid support has the proper bearing. (See second short paragraph in my answer) SDS screws are a better choice over drywall screws, but the cleaned surface and const. adhesive was to add the shear strength. Drywall screws on their own are case hardened, quite strong.

Comment: I can assure you this old growth 2x4 lumber is not just different in size.  It is about twice as dense has twice as many rings.  @auuja Correct: drywall screws are quite weak in shear (they are too brittle).